# Merge 2 SELECT statement in one result table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, merge

I have 2 different select statements, both of which generate similar tables. How can I put the result from both of them in one table?
Example:

First SELECT generates

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A     X     Y
B     X     Z
```

The second SELECT generates

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A     Z     Z
C     X     X
```

And I want the result to be

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A     X     Y
B     X     Z
A     Z     Z
C     X     X
```

Comment: You should use `UNION ALL` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html
And to add the result in another table, you should use the syntax `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

Comment: Thank you Dorian. That worked flawlessly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` if you want duplicate data.

Remember that column name and type must be same in two queries.

For example

```
SELECT
col1,
col2
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT
col1,
col2
FROM table2
```

Comment: Yes, they have identical columns in my case. That worked great, Thank you